# not able to change save in pg_hba.conf of compute engine

Tags: postgresql, google-compute-engine

I want to set up PostgreSQL on Compute Engine but when try to change **pg_hba.conf**
by `sudo nano ../../etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf` and I paste `# IPv4 remote connections for the tutorial: host    all             all           [YOUR_IPV4_ADDRESS]/32         md5` with my local computer IP address and press`Control+x` then data not saved

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to follow steps provided at the community tutorial [How to set up PostgreSQL on Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-postgres) and found no issues. Keep in mind that **some software versions mentioned in this tutorial are outdated and should be replaced with supported ones** and, as a result, **file paths should be updated** as well.

Please have a look at my steps below:

1. Create VM instance (because Ubuntu 14.04 from the tutorial is outdated I replaced it with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS).

   ```
   $ gcloud compute instances create instance-1 --zone=europe-west3-a --machine-type=e2-medium --image=ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20200701 --image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud 
   Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/test-prj/zones/europe-west3-a/instances/instance-1].
   NAME        ZONE            MACHINE_TYPE  PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP    EXTERNAL_IP     STATUS
   instance-1  europe-west3-a  e2-medium                  10.156.15.192  35.246.XXX.YYY  RUNNING
   ```
2. Install PostgreSQL and use PSQL to complete the setup:

   ```
   $ sudo apt update
   $ sudo apt upgrade
   $ sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-client postgresql-contrib 
   $ sudo -u postgres psql postgres
   psql (10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))
   Type "help" for help.

   postgres=# \password postgres
   Enter new password: 
   Enter it again: 
   postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION adminpack;
   CREATE EXTENSION
   postgres=# \q
   $
   ```

   PostgreSQL 9.3 was replaced with 10.12.
3. Configure PostgreSQL remote access:

   3.1. edit `pg_hba.conf`:

   - navigate to [ip4.me](http://ip4.me/) to get the IPv4 address of your local computer (external);
     [image: external_ip_of_local_pc]
   - open file `/etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf` (file path was changed because of newer version):

     ```
     $ sudo nano /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf
     ```
   - scroll down to the bottom of the file and add the following lines:

     ```
     # IPv4 remote connections for the tutorial:
     host    all             all           [YOUR_IPV4_ADDRESS]/32         md5
     ```
   - replace [YOUR_IPV4_ADDRESS] with the address of your local computer:

     ```
     # IPv4 remote connections for the tutorial:
     host    all             all             89.64.XXX.YYY/32          md5
     ```
   - save the file and exit the editor;
   - check changes:

     ```
     $ sudo cat /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf
     ...
     # Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
     local   all             postgres                                peer

     # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

     # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
     local   all             all                                     peer
     # IPv4 local connections:
     host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
     # IPv6 local connections:
     host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
     # Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
     # replication privilege.
     local   replication     all                                     peer
     host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
     host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
     # IPv4 remote connections for the tutorial:
     host    all             all             89.64.XXX.YYY/32          md5
     ```

   3.2. edit `postgresql.conf`

   - open file `/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf` (file path was changed because of newer version):

     ```
     $ sudo nano /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf
     ```
   - scroll down to the line that begins with `#listen_addresses = 'localhost'`;
   - delete the `#` character to uncomment the line;
   - replace `localhost` with `*` (the '*' setting enables Postgres to listen on all IP addresses);
   - save the file and exit the editor;
   - restart the database service:

     ```
     $ sudo service postgresql restart
     $ sudo service postgresql status
       ● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: active (exited) since Tue 2020-07-14 09:57:07 UTC; 6s ago
       Process: 7452 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
       Main PID: 7452 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

       Jul 14 09:57:07 instance-1 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
       Jul 14 09:57:07 instance-1 systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
     ```